# Mvvmcross MvxSpinner Validation

Tags: c#, android, validation, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am trying to find a way to validated if the user have selected the appropriate value from the spinner. Here is my code for spinner:

```
<MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxSpinner
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/secondBP1"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6.5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6.5dp"
        local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_shippingtocountry"
        local:MvxDropDownItemTemplate="item_spinnerdropdown"
        local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Country;SelectedItem SelectedCountry; Error Errors['SelectedPackageType']" />
```

I am using [Mvvm Validation helper library](https://github.com/pglazkov/MvvmValidation). I have edit text validation working for my applilcation but I don't know how should I validated my spinner. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What you want is trigger a command when the user chooses an item in the spinner ?

Answer (score 0):

> find a way to validated if the user have selected the appropriate value from the spinner

Try to bind on `HandleItemSelected` property. It's attempt an `ICommand` value.

```
<MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views.MvxSpinner
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textSize="40dp"
  local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_spinner"
  local:MvxDropDownItemTemplate="@layout/item_spinnerdropdown"
  local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items;SelectedItem SelectedItem;HandleItemSelected MyCommand" 
  />
```

Then your command will look something like:

```
private MvxCommand<string> _subunitSelectedCommand;
public ICommand MyCommand =>
     _subunitSelectedCommand =
            (_subunitSelectedCommand ?? new MvxCommand<string>(OnSubunitSelected));

private void OnSubunitSelected(string name)
{
    //Do your validated logic
}
```